# iOS11 check or change an app's storage location setting

Tags: ios, storage, settings, document, ios11

I have recently discovered that an app that I am developing can run into issues if users have chosen that they want the apps storage location to be set to anything different from "Local Storage".

It seems that iOS11 allows any app that uses documents to change the Document Storage placement to any place, even if the app internally does not support iCloud storage, as a result I am getting bad reviews from frustrated users that are changing the default setting to iCloud (or some other cloud vendor) and then realizing that it does not work.

I would like to stop them from changing this setting as in my case it does not make any sense (you don't want to be constantly storing caches of temporary files on the cloud) but I can't seem to find a way to change this (it's an Apple Settings app thing) or at least check the value so I can inform about it's current setting.

Showing a message for all users regardless of what their setting is seems like an extreme solution, so I'd like to know if anyone has managed to find a way to either query the value or change it, any will do for me.

Comment: It sounds like your app is using a document when it shouldn't be.  You should either change your strategy for storing temporary files to use the on-device temp directory or ensure that your app works with whatever document store the user has selected.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 thanks for your reply, the truth is that the caches are stored where Apple recommends(NSCachesDirectory)this was perhaps a poor choice on my side to use as an example, as I can't quite disclose publicly which "important" files are being stored in the local storage,or what they are there for, the point is that they must remain local to the device,and an external iOS11"setting" that I don't know if I can opt out of, is breaking my app and causing confusion and irritation amongst my customers. I think that as an app developer I should have a way to opt-out or query this settings value